# Flutter pod install error with firebase messaging on ios

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

Command "pod install" can't be executed when run on ios flutter app folder.

Error as the following:

Analyzing dependencies
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.6' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.0.6' defined in 'firebase_core'

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Messaging":
In Podfile:
firebase_messaging (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`) was resolved to 10.0.6, which depends on
Firebase/Messaging (= 10.0.6)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Messaging (= 10.0.6)`.

You have either:

- out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
- mistyped the name or version.
- not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

We have this package on pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_core: ^1.6.0
firebase_messaging: ^10.0.6
```

on podfile:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
```

We use pod version:

```
1.11.0.rc.1
```

macOS Big Sur version:

```
11.2.1
```

If we delete this packages from pubspec.yaml, pod install work fine.

We tried many ways to no avail!

- pod install --repo-update this donst help;
- also cocoa pods installation in M1 dosnt resolve this problem;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was resolved using this command

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Thank you for all!

Answer (score 17):

Always when you add a new dependency on IOS you should do:

```
cd ios/
rm -rf Pods/
rm -rf Podfile.lock
cd ..
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
pod install --repo-update ( if needed)
```

This always help me to fix dependencies issues on IOS

Comment: We tried these instructions more than once! The problem is still there

Comment: in that exact order?

Comment: Yes as you write!

Comment: Try to upgrade the firebase_core and firebase_messaging to the latest version

Comment: How to upgrade firebase_core and firebase_messaging? if you mean version of flutter plugin, we use the latest version of this plugins published on pub.dev

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot with the error output

Comment: one of the most valuable things i learned on stack overflow is that the most unpopular answer with least amount of upvotes is the actual solution to the OPs question.

Comment: this worked for me, on mont

Comment: Using the last one alone worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone showed here, I fixed this by running the **pod update** command inside the *iOS* directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem, Solved by Run.

```
flutter pub cache repair

pod install --repo-update
```